# Jenkins Build Failure Notification - MS Teams

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, email-notifications

I had set-up notifications via Microsoft Teams for my jenkins job - success, failure, abort, etc.

```
pipeline {
  options {
    office365ConnectorWebhooks([[
                startNotification: true,
                notifySuccess: true,
                notifyFailure: true,
                notifyAborted: true,
                notifyBackToNormal: true,
                    url: 'webhook_url'
        ]]
    )
} }
```

With the help of above script i am receiving notifications for all except the failure notifications.

Even i aborted the job i am receiving the notification.

Can anyone help on this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a notification step regardless of the pipeline completion status using the `post` section and the `always` condition like the following:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test notification') {
            steps {
                echo "Let's simulate a failure"
                error('Failing the build.')
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always { 
            echo 'I will always run!'
            office365ConnectorSend status: currentBuild.currentResult, webhookUrl: 'webhook_url'
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the syntax has changed.
To learn more about the plugin usage:

[Office 365 Connector plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/Office-365-Connector/#plugin-content-pipeline-post-section)

[Office 365 Connector steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/Office-365-Connector/)

And about the Jenkins post usage:
[Jenkins Pipeline Syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post)